# iOS Xcode issue with CameraViewController when I click on a photo to choose it

Tags: ios, xcode

hoping for some insight. I have an issue with my Xcode app when I run it in simulator iPhone 6 iOS 8 or on my iPhone 4s iOS 8.0.2. The issue is that when I click on my photo tab to access CameraViewController the image picker code works fine in both situations (photo library for simulator and camera for iPhone)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
_imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;


}
else {
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

}
self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];


[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Then when I click on a photo in simulator or take a photo with my iPhone and click on use photo the chosen image and fields that are there to be edited appears for a split second and then it goes back to image picker view to pick another photo (just keeps looping around like that.

here is my code for imagepickercontroller:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.chosenImageView.image = chosenImage;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Possible additional info in case you need it:
my Xcode is 6.0.1
my Base SDK is Latest iOS (iOS 8.0)
my Deployment Target 7.1

I did not alter any of these other than updating my when notified

any insight to fix this issue will be much appreciated

Grazie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I can see is that you are **presenting** the UIImagePickerContoller at `ViewWillAppear` or I can say you are performing the task of picking an image at `ViewWillAppear`.

`ViewWillAppear` gets called every time the ViewController will become active. This is leading your app in the loop of picking the image since the `ViewWillAppear` will be called again when   the `UIImagePickerController` will be dismissed when  `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is called. Place a **BREAK POINT** at `ViewWillAppear` to check it yourself.

Try to move your code somewhere else other than `ViewWillAppear`.

You can place a button  or something like that and write the same code in its `-IBAction`, that you have written in `ViewWillAppear`.

Comment: Thanks RoOmin, it worked...I added a Take Photo button in the navigation bar and added the code to the IBACTION from ViewWillAppear